# Javascript detect input value programatic change in chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to write a plugin for Chrome browser on windows, basically adding extra functionality to a website.
EDIT: The website is not mine, so I can only add what is possible from the chrome extention.

There is this piece of html...
`<input type="hidden" class="k-textbox" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="">`

The value is updated by some other Javascript run on the page.
I need to detect this change somehow, including detecting when the value is reset to as above.

Obviously keyup, keydown, blur etc don't work as its hidden.

I thought onchange might work but doesnt?
`document.getElementById('UserID').onchange = function(){alert(document.getElementById("UserID").value);};`

I currently have...
    `var user = document.getElementById("UserID").value`
running every 5 Seconds but it only seems to pick up the first change and never updates that value.

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

Code im using:

```
var user = document.getElementById("UserID").value
if (user > 0) {
var iss_pop = document.getElementById("issuingPopup").childNodes;
org_html = iss_pop[1].innerHTML;
new_html = "<a href='https://website.com/#" + document.getElementById('UserID').value + "'>" + org_html + "</a>";
iss_pop[1].innerHTML = new_html;
};
```

Comment: As you mentioned : `I currently have...  var user = document.getElementById("UserID").value running every 5 Seconds but it only seems to pick up the first change and never updates that value.` This is a good starting point. Just show us the what you tried, and we may gladly help. `**Note : You can use code snippet of the editor, when you add or edit a question**`

Comment: Here is the code I am using

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `onchange` looks for a "real", ie: by a user, event. Since you're using Javascript to change the value of the hidden field `onchange` never gets fired.

Whenever you set the `UserID`'s value with javascript use this to trigger the event:

```
document.getElementById('UserID').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kx0kedqp/)

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear, the website I am adding functionality too isn't mine. That why im using a chrome plugin and is exactly the problem, I don't update UserID with my code so I cant call any other functions or triggers.